# Kubectl connection refused existing cluster

Tags: kubernetes, connection, controls, cluster-computing

Hope someone can help me.
To describe the situation in short, I have a self managed k8s cluster, running on 3 machines (1 master, 2 worker nodes). In order to make it HA, I attempted to add a second master to the cluster.
After some failed attempts, I found out that I needed to add `controlPlaneEndpoint` configuration to kubeadm-config config map. So I did, with `masternodeHostname:6443`.

I generated the certificate and join command for the second master, and after running it on the second master machine, it failed with

```
error execution phase control-plane-join/etcd: error creating local etcd static pod manifest file: timeout waiting for etcd cluster to be available
```

Checking the first master now, I get connection refused for the IP on port 6443. So I cannot run any kubectl commands.
Tried recreating the .kube folder, with all the config copied there, no luck.
Restarted kubelet, docker.
The containers running on the cluster seem ok, but I am locked out of any cluster configuration (dashboard is down, kubectl commands not working).
Is there any way I make it work again? Not losing any of the configuration or the deployments already present?
Thanks! Sorry if it’s a noob question.

Cluster information:

```
Kubernetes version: 1.15.3
Cloud being used: (put bare-metal if not on a public cloud) bare-metal
Installation method: kubeadm
Host OS: RHEL 7
CNI and version: weave 0.3.0
CRI and version: containerd 1.2.6
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old, known problem with Kubernetes `1.15` <sup>[[1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1712),[2](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/15637)]</sup>.
It is caused by short etcd timeout period. As far as I'm aware it is a hard coded value in [source](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/etcd/etcd.go#L41-L43), and cannot be changed (feature request to make it configurable is open for version [`1.22`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/2463)).
Your best bet would be to upgrade to a newer version, and recreate your cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the response :D. So other than recreate the cluster from scratch, I have no way of keeping my old cluster configuration and deployments?

Comment: You can try `kubeadm reset` on original master, and then `kubeadm init` again, but I'm not 100% sure it will solve your problem.